# php fatal exception handling with arrayObject

Tags: php, object, exception

Need help with exception handling for arrayObject. I'm iterating through a series of objects but when the offset ends fatal exception occurs. The code is:

```
while ($c <= 10) {
    $num = 1;
    $b = $c-$num;
    $object_to_iterate = $q[$b];
    $obj = new ArrayObject ($object_to_iterate);
    iterateObject($obj);
    $c ++;
}
```

The error is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException'
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Without any context or explanation of `$b`, `$c`, `$q` or `$num`, it'd be really hard to figure this out...

Comment: i'm sure that the fatal exception relates to 'new ArrayObject'. I think I need to catch the ArrayObject when the $b offset is empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I don't know if this is the best way to do it but I used the following code:

```
while ($c <= 10) {
$num = 1;
$b = $c-$num;
$object_to_iterate = $q[$b];
//exception handling
if (empty($q[$b])) {
break;
} else {
$obj = new ArrayObject($object_to_iterate);
iterateObject($obj); 
}
$c ++;
}
```

It works through

Answer (score 0):

from the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.construct.php):

```
The input parameter accepts an array or an Object.
```

Now as @BoltClock said: it is really hard to figure out without knowing what b, c, q and num are, but if q is an array, then

```
$object_to_iterate = $q[$b];
```

might be just a string? And then

```
$obj = new ArrayObject ($object_to_iterate);
```

has an argument that is not an object or array?
Maybe do a `var_dump()` on that `$object_to_iterate`, and check is it is an array or object.

Comment: I thought is might be that the $q object is trying to find $b offset which is a number and that number isn't there so then the ArrayObject tries to use the $q[$b] it is empty and an exception is thrown. Does that make sense?

Comment: It could be, but even if the offset $b is there, it could be that $q[$b] isn't an object, something we can't know without actually being told what is inside $q. So in the end, the goal is to check if that `object_to_iterate` is actually an object (or array).

Answer (score 0):

What does $c start as? If 0 (which is likely), then $b = -1 and you're trying to get $q[-1], which, again, likely doesn't exist. So you're not really passing anything to the ArrayObject constructor.

Comment: I think that is correct but I'm having trouble working out the code to stop this type of exception happening because I don't know how many objects exist i.e. it could be anything from 1 to 10?

Comment: Use is_object() before to test if $object_to_iterate is an object